# Extract Value with Regex

Tags: regex, extract

looking for some help to extract this

> 1f0a4999e47767aed6e2e7ed00bc3743

from this

> additional_src.setAttribute('src', '/1f0a4999e47767aed6e2e7ed00bc3743');

hope someone can help me.

Kind regards. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a 32-bytes hexadecimal hash, I would use this regular expression :

```
[0-9a-f]{32}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/\w+(?=["']\);)/g` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Be aware that the `/pattern/flags` syntax isn't a regex feature but rather a language dependent syntax. It may confuse OP if his language doesn't implement it.